# AWS Setup with Serverless v1 After Lambda Runtime End-of-Life

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, eol, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a few projects on AWS using the following setup:

•   Cognito - (user pools)

•   S3 - (frontend)

•   Cloudfront - (CDN proxies)

•   API Gateway - (REST APIs)

•   Lambda NodeJS 14 - (backend logic)

•   DATA API - (to make DB queries using data-api-client NPM package)

•   Aurora MySQL (compatible with MySQL 5.7.2.08.3) - Serverless v1 (database)

These projects are mainly for development or internal purposes. Hence they are rarely used. Thanks to Serverless v1 database, I can set it to 0 ACU when idle, so basically we are only paying around 1-2$ per month.

Now I learned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) that NodeJS 14 is going to deprecate on November 2023. I have a few questions regarding that:

1. I can still use the existing system after Deprecation Phase 2 as is, right?
2. What if I want to create the same system for a new project after Deprecation Phase 2? Is there going to be any way to create a deprecated Lambda NodeJS version? Maybe using CLI v2?
3. If I choose to upgrade to NodeJS 18, then I have to use Serverless v2. In that case, Data API is not supported, so I will need to use RDS Proxy, correct?
4. Since Serverless v2 can only go to 0.5 ACU, I would need to pay around minimum 40$ per database per month, correct? So in comparison to 2$ for Serverless v1, it becomes 240$ for 6 databases. Is there a better way to optimize the costs?
5. Is switching to DynamoDB the cheaper option? But then I need to change the DB, Lambda function and all queries for it.

Comment: "If I choose to upgrade to NodeJS 18, then I have to use Serverless v2" How did you come up with that conclusion? The Aurora serverless database version is **completely unrelated** to the NodeJS version you are running in AWS Lambda.

Comment: @MarkB because [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda) it says "If your existing Lambda functions are using the included SDK v2, then you must update your function code to use the SDK v3 when upgrading to the Node.js 18 runtime.". And [here](https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client/issues/127) it says data-api-client is not supported with SDK v3. Since I cannot use Data API, I cannot use Serverless v1. Is my assumption wrong? Is there a way to send DB queries from SDK v3 Lambda to Serverless v1 DB?

Comment: According to that last link, it is the `typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver` library that is incompatible with AWS SDK v3. AWS SDK v3 itself has suport for the data-api as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/rds-data/ You would only have an upgrade issue if you were using that third-party `typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver` library. If you are using that third-party library you should track this issue: https://github.com/ArsenyYankovsky/typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver/issues/148

Comment: Thanks for the info @MarkB. Then I should just ditch the 3rd party library and stick to SDK v3 data-api and all should be good.